# Concise way to convert multiple Date Time to seconds?

Tags: python

I am looking for a way to write the code below in a more concise manner. I thought about trying df[timemonths] = pd.to_timedelta(df[timemonths])...
but it did not work (arg must be a string, timedelta, list, tuple, 1-d array, or Series).

Appreciate any help. Thanks

```
timemonths = ['TimeFromPriorRTtoSRS', 'TimetoAcuteG3','TimetoLateG3',
                 'TimeSRStoLastFUDeath','TimeDiagnosistoLastFUDeath',
                 'TimetoRecurrence']

monthsec = 2.628e6 # to convert to months

df.TimetoLocalRecurrence = pd.to_timedelta(df.TimetoLocalRecurrence).dt.total_seconds()/monthsec

df.TimeFromPriorRTtoSRS = pd.to_timedelta(df.TimeFromPriorRTtoSRS).dt.total_seconds()/monthsec

df.TimetoAcuteG3 = pd.to_timedelta(df.TimetoAcuteG3).dt.total_seconds()/monthsec

df.TimetoLateG3 = pd.to_timedelta(df.TimetoLateG3).dt.total_seconds()/monthsec

df.TimeSRStoLastFUDeath = pd.to_timedelta(df.TimeSRStoLastFUDeath).dt.total_seconds()/monthsec

df.TimeDiagnosistoLastFUDeath = pd.to_timedelta(df.TimeDiagnosistoLastFUDeath).dt.total_seconds()/monthsec

df.TimetoRecurrence = pd.to_timedelta(df.TimetoRecurrence).dt.total_seconds()/monthsec
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could write your operation as a lambda function and then apply it to the relevant columns:

```
timemonths = ['TimeFromPriorRTtoSRS', 'TimetoAcuteG3','TimetoLateG3',
             'TimeSRStoLastFUDeath','TimeDiagnosistoLastFUDeath',
             'TimetoRecurrence']
monthsec = 2.628e6
convert_to_months = lambda x: pd.to_timedelta(x).dt.total_seconds()/monthsec
df[timemonths] = df[timemonths].apply(convert_to_months)
```

Granted I am kind of guessing here since you haven't provided any example data to work with.

Comment: Sorry you are right I should have added example data. My apologies but you were right. I am sad that I didnt think about using lambda. At least I will be more aware for next time and now I have your great example to work from in the future. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

### Iterate over `vars()` of `df`

**Disclaimer:** this solution will most likely only work if the `df` class doesn't have any other variables.

The way this works is by simply moving the repetitive code after the `=` to a function.

```
def convert(times):
  monthsec = 2.628e6
  return {
    key: pd.to_timedelta(value).dt.total_seconds()/monthsec
    for key, value in times.items()
  }
```

#### Now we have to apply this function to each variable.

The problem here is that it can be tedious to apply it to each variable individually, so we could use your list `timemonths` to apply it based on the keys, however, this requires us to create an array of keys manually like so:

```
timemonths = ['TimeFromPriorRTtoSRS', 'TimetoAcuteG3','TimetoLateG3', 'TimeSRStoLastFUDeath','TimeDiagnosistoLastFUDeath', 'TimetoRecurrence']
```

And this can be annoying, especially if you add more, or take away some because you have to keep updating this array.

So instead, let's dynamically iterate over every variable in `df`

```
for key, value in convert(vars(df)).items():
  setattr(df, key, value)
```

**Full Code:**

```
def convert(times):
  monthsec = 2.628e6
  return {
    key: pd.to_timedelta(value).dt.total_seconds()/monthsec
    for key, value in times.items()
  }

for key, value in convert(vars(df)).items():
  setattr(df, key, value)
```

---

#### Sidenote

The reason I am using `setattr` is because when examining your code, I came to the conclusion that `df` was most likely a class instance, and as such, properties (by this I mean variables like `self.variable = ...`) of a class instance must by modified via `setattr` and not `df['variable'] = ...`.

Comment: Thank you! I look forward to trying this when I get home

Comment: Thank you so much. It also prompted me to look up setattr in greater detail

Comment: @MikeDoho you're welcome, and if you like this method better you could mark it as the answer